# Bramhacharya and restriction on cosmetics

Tags: dharma, life, dharma-shastras, bramhacharya

Dharma shastras restrict Bramhacharis from applying perfumes and oils. Is it possible that Moisturiser is also restricted, and if yes, then is there any shastra advice for sweaty and dry skin bramhacharis what should they do if they have to avoid the sin of applying cosmetics.

Comment: "what is remedy for sweaty and dry skin...what should they do" -- sounds like personal advice question.

Comment: @sv. Well I am not the only bramhachari, this is directed to the whole category of people living in bramhacharya ashrama phase. In anycase I have changed question language.

Comment: @Yogi - You are correct this rule is given in puranas, but i think that is only for the brahmacharis who are living and studying in Guru-Kulas.Not 100% sure though.

Comment: You have basically 2 questions 1-Is using moisturizer prohibited for brahmacharis? and 2-then is there any shastra advice for sweaty and dry skin bramhacharis what should they do if they have to avoid the sin of applying cosmetics.? Although ur intent may be genuine both questions are seemingly not quite related to Hinduism(off-topic+ bit of personal advice) ..I voted for closure..How will a Dharma Shastra differentiate between a cosmetic(oil,perfumes) and a moisturizer?!

Answer (score 2):

**Moisturiser is also restricted, and there is no circumventing that.**

As you said, Dharmashastras restrict Brahmacharis from applying perfumes:

> agandha sevī || 25 || 
> 25. Nor use perfumes.
>
> Apastamba Sutra 1.1.2

They also restrict moisturiser:

> utsanna ślāghaḥ || 27 || 
> 27. Nor embellish oneself [by using ointments and the like].
>
> Apastamba Sutra 1.1.2

> 2.178. [Let him abstain] **from anointing (his body)**, applying collyrium to his eyes, from the use of shoes and of an umbrella (or parasol), from (sensual) desire, anger, covetousness, dancing, singing, and playing (musical instruments)
>
> Manu Smriti

> 1.33. The honey, meat, **massage of body with ghee etc.** and collyrium of eye, defiled (residual) food of others (except the teacher), harsh words, coition with any woman, slaughtering animals, looking at the Sun (at the time of Sunrise and Sunset), obscene speech (untrue or abuse), criticism etc. **should be abandoned because, these are prohibited for a Brahmachari**.
>
> Yajnavalkya Smriti

However, these rules only apply to brahmacharis studying in Guru-Kulas:

> 2.175. But a **student who resides with his teacher** must observe the following restrictive rules, duly controlling all his organs, in order to increase his spiritual merit.
>
> Manu Smriti

Now, about shastra reason (notice bolded part):

> 2.175. But a student who resides with his teacher must observe the following restrictive rules, **duly controlling all his organs, in order to increase his spiritual merit**.
>
> Manu Smriti

Applying moisture does not contribute to spiritual merit (and hinders it), so it is to be avoided.